# Changing to a new CMS - Search Console

Tags: google, cms

I want to move my eCommerce site currently running on wordress and woocommerce to a different CMS (Prestashop) The current site only has about 100 pages indexed.

My question is can I remove the site from search console and re-add the domain when I'm done with the new site?

The current site does not have a lot of traffic as I only added it two months or so ago so. I'm not to worried about loosing traffic.

Comment: What "search console" are you talking about?  And what makes you think that you can't do that?

Comment: @Steve Google Search Console is what used to be called Google Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have changed the CMS, one thing I would recommend you do is removing the 'old cms sitemap' replace it with the 'new one'.

I also recommend checking that the same version of your website should be submitted into the Search Console. If your website is accessible using http://www.example.com then it should be submitted with 'http' and 'www'.

These two things needs to be taken care in Google Search Console once you change website CMS.

Comment: Great thanks, I will probably get a bunch of 404 errors that I have to redirect once the new CMS is live?

Comment: Yes, you will need to redirect the OLD CMS pages to the relevant New CMS pages.